# "FOREIGN KEY constraint failed" when updating dependent tables during a transaction

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables with a chain dependencies like this:

```
pragma foreign_keys = ON;
create table foo (id integer primary key);
create table bar (id integer primary key references foo(id));
create table baz (id integer primary key references bar(id));
insert into foo values (1), (2);
insert into bar values (1);
insert into baz values (1);
```

I want to update the child tables `bar` and `baz`. However, when updating them within a transation, I get an error:

```
begin;
update bar set id = 2 where id = 1;
update baz set id = 2 where id = 1;
commit;
-- Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

How can I update the child table simultaneously to avoid the foreign key constraint error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes I wish I could read the [docs](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_deferred) more carefully.

> Each foreign key constraint in SQLite is classified as either immediate or deferred. **Foreign key constraints are immediate by default.**(...)
>
> If a statement modifies the contents of the database so that an **immediate foreign key constraint** is in violation at the conclusion the statement, **an exception is thrown** and the effects of the statement are reverted. By contrast, if a statement modifies the contents of the database such that a **deferred foreign key constraint** is violated, **the violation is not reported immediately. Deferred foreign key constraints are not checked until the transaction tries to COMMIT.**

So a table can declare a foreign key as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` to allow this kind of update.

```
pragma foreign_keys = ON;
create table foo (id integer primary key);
create table bar (id integer primary key references foo(id) deferrable initially deferred);
create table baz (id integer primary key references bar(id) deferrable initially deferred);
insert into foo values (1), (2);
insert into bar values (1);
insert into baz values (1);

begin;
update bar set id = 2 where id = 1;
update baz set id = 2 where id = 1;
commit;
```

But as sqlite does not easily allow to alter a table, it is nice to know that it is possible to obtain this behavior on existing tables that have immediate foreign keys with the `defer_foreign_keys` pragma:

```
pragma foreign_keys = ON;
create table foo (id integer primary key);
create table bar (id integer primary key references foo(id));
create table baz (id integer primary key references bar(id));
insert into foo values (1), (2);
insert into bar values (1);
insert into baz values (1);

pragma defer_foreign_keys=ON;
begin;
update bar set id = 2 where id = 1;
update baz set id = 2 where id = 1;
commit;
```

I must say, I don't understand the use of immediate foreign keys, and I don't see why they should be the default -- except perhaps for performance reasons?

Answer (score 2):

If you set `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on each foreign key, the changes in the primary key side of the relationship should be propagated to the field on the foreign side. It can be set like this:

```
create table foo (id integer primary key);
create table bar (id integer primary key references foo(id) on update cascade);
create table baz (id integer primary key references bar(id) on update cascade);
```

Then you should just need to update bar.id like so, and the change will occur automatically in baz.id.

```
begin;
update bar set id = 2 where id = 1;
commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to avoid this...  but...

```
begin;
delete baz where id = 1;
delete bar where id = 1;
insert into bar values (2);
insert into baz values (2);
commit;
```